# Transforming data while importing csv into mysql

Tags: mysql

importing csv file and transform a column while importing

1.i tried using data type date_time DATETIME NOT NULL:
i get Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column 'date_time' at row 1

2.i tried using data type date_time int NOT NULL:
i get Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column 'date_time' at row 1

in the file incomes.csv the column time is represented:
    time - header
    1546361872 - value

```
CREATE TABLE incoming (
user_id  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
url  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
domain VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
date_time DATETIME NOT NULL
);

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server
8.0/Uploads/incomes.csv'
INTO TABLE incoming  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS
SET  date_time = FROM_UNIXTIME(date_time
);

 example of first 4 rows of csv file (including headers)

  | user_id |   domain   |    time    |
  |    1    | @gmail.com | 1546366951 |
  |    2    | @gmail.com | 1546354528 |
  |    3    | @gmail.com | 1546365429 |
```

i expected to see date_time converted from unix time format in a datetime format

what am i doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: A couple of rows from your csv file would help.

Comment: That's not quite the way to transform rows read from a csv file - you need to push the timestamp into a user defined variable then apply the from_unixtimestamp function.please review Input Preprocessing here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html